# Survey form builder using Jquery PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, forms, builder, survey

I'm trying to create a Survey builder wizard that would be embedded in the website.

Users will be able to create their own surveys by dragging and dropping appropriate form elements such as checkboxes, radiobuttons etc

Once the user creates his survey br dragging and dropping the appropriate form elements such as radiocontrol, checkboxes - He should be able to save the created survey and publish it.

While going about doing this I came up with the following questions:

1. I could build my own drag and drop form building wizard - but is there any open source plugin/code out there so that i dont need to reinvent the wheel ?
2. How the should the form structure be saved ?

   Should the form elements with the associated text be saved in a database (mysql) and rebuilt on the fly when someone accesses the survey link on the mobile ?

   Should I be looking at XML/JSON to store the html form structure

Would appreciate any help !

Comment: Hi,

With BSD licence :

 - https://github.com/spiral-project/daybed/
 - https://github.com/spiral-project/backbone-daybed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one that we're using now to put a form builder on our client's website.
http://www.botsko.net/blog/2009/04/07/jquery-form-builder-plugin/

The form can be serialized to both JSON and XML.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) for the drag and drop operations. I would make use the [grid functionality](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#snap-to) provided.

To save the form I'd make standardized representations of the elements in a JSON format and save those.
This representation should include the `left` and `top` css attributes (for positioning) and a subset of styles and attributes which your users can assign their input fields.

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness

At the time I posted the question, this was not available or else I would have opted for this to build the front end : 
http://getfuelux.com/formbuilder.html